# Iterate over a arrays of strings and perform sql queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a table called 'A' with an array of strings. I want to loop through each string(part of a array) in a Column of Table 'A' and match the string in Table 'B' and return with columns from both Table 'A' and Table 'B'.

It is not a sql error but I am looking for suggestions to implement this with a sql query.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: can be a interesting question, looks like some join on varchar type query problem. But the question is not fully understandable. Please edit your question and add some sample exmple of what your both tables look like and your expected output